# Loop through dataframe in python to select specific row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a **timeseries data** of **5864 ICU Patients** and my dataframe is like this. Each row is the ICU stay of respective patient at a particular hour.

| HR | SBP | DBP | ICULOS | Sepsis | P_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 92 | 120 | 80 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 98 | 115 | 85 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 93 | 125 | 75 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 95 | 130 | 90 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 102 | 120 | 80 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 109 | 115 | 75 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 94 | 135 | 100 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 97 | 100 | 70 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 85 | 120 | 80 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 88 | 115 | 75 | 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 93 | 125 | 85 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 78 | 130 | 90 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 115 | 140 | 110 | 3 | 0 | 2 |
| 102 | 120 | 80 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| 98 | 140 | 110 | 5 | 1 | 2 |

I want to select the ICULOS where Sepsis = 1 (first hour only) based on patient ID. Like in P_ID = 0, Sepsis = 1 at ICULOS = 3. I did this on a single patient (the dataframe having data of only a single patient) using the code:

```
x = df[df['Sepsis'] == 1]["ICULOS"].values[0]
print("ICULOS at which Sepsis Label = 1 is:", x)
# Output
ICULOS at which Sepsis Label = 1 is: 46
```

If I want to check it for each P_ID, I have to do this 5864 times. Can someone help me with the code using a loop? The loop will go to each P_ID and then give the result of ICULOS where Sepsis = 1. Looking forward for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in df['P_ID'].unique():

   print(df.query('P_ID == @x and Sepsis == 1')['ICULOS'][0])
```

Comment: `UndefinedVariableError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: Corrected. Try now

Comment: got this error `KeyError: 0`

Comment: `print(df.query('P_ID == @x and Sepsis == 1')['ICULOS'].values[0])` And if so

Comment: And are there any patients in the dataframes who don't have Sepsis == 1?

Comment: 2932 patients are non-sepsis. They don't have sepsis = 1

Answer (score 0):

First, filter the rows which have *Sepsis=1*. It will automatically filter the P_IDs which don't have Sepsis as 1. Thus, you will have fewer patients to iterate.

```
df1 = df[df.Sepsis==1]
for pid in df.P_ID.unique():
    if pid not in df.P_ID:
        print("P_ID: {pid} - it has no iclus at Sepsis Lable = 1")
    else:
        iclus = df1[df1.P_ID==pid].ICULOS.values[0]
        print(f"P_ID: {pid} - ICULOS at which Sepsis Label = 1 is: {iclus}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want all patients, I downsampled my data from 40k patients to ~6k patients.

Comment: check the edit. You will run the query for all patients. If a patient doesn't have data for sepsis label = 1, it will execute the else condition.

Comment: Thanks Labiba for the answer